# Extracting a pivot field one level up in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I have a many-to-many relationship with a pivot table. The two models in the relationship are **Communities** and **Personas**. In the pivot table, I have the IDs of the instances in relationship and an extra field called "member_count" to count the amount of members in that specific relationship. To access the member count field, I include the following function in my **Community** model to always have it returned:

```
public function personas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Persona')->withPivot('member_count');
}
```

This results in the following being returned when I retrieve Communities:

```
{
    "id": "3304806f-9172-4690-b9b7-fa672319eaef",
    "name": "Some Community",
    "site_id": "ee09da48-9ba6-42a9-9f72-4d3ca06ffd2f",
    "internal_external": "internal",
    "created_at": "2020-09-11T14:36:23.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-11T14:36:23.000000Z",
    "personas": [
        {
            "id": "1447bc79-f54e-49eb-b33d-acc1c43633e5",
            "name": "Some Persona",
            "created_at": "2020-09-11T14:41:27.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-11T14:41:27.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "community_id": "3304806f-9172-4690-b9b7-fa672319eaef",
                "persona_id": "1447bc79-f54e-49eb-b33d-acc1c43633e5",
                "member_count": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "ca53ec58-a4e8-4330-a5c3-8dea2235b01f",
            "name": "Another Persona",
            "created_at": "2020-09-11T14:41:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-11T14:41:15.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "community_id": "3304806f-9172-4690-b9b7-fa672319eaef",
                "persona_id": "ca53ec58-a4e8-4330-a5c3-8dea2235b01f",
                "member_count": 5
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

I want to move the **member_count** field one level up to just be returned as part of the Persona object. Is there a way to do this built in to Laravel?

Comment: you can do that by using a custom DB Query. I don't think there is a way of doing it directly with Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

in think you can make [addSelect](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_addSelect) inside your eager loading ....

```
   $value = Community::where('id', 1)->with(['personas'=> function ($query) {
            $query->join('communities_personas', 'personas.id', 'communities_personas.personas_id')->
            addSelect(['communities_personas.member_count,communities_personas.personas_id']);
        }])->get();
```

i'm not sure about your tables and models name, please correct the wrong ones ...

and make sure you also addselect the foreign key between the personas table and the pivot table.